# Send multiple values for one form param in clj-http?

Tags: api, http, clojure, authorize.net

```
(defn do-request [url query-map]
  "Executes HTTP client"
  (client/post url {:form-params query-map}))

(do-request "http://foo.com/api" {:a [val1 val2 val3]})
```

I need to send multiple values for a single key. The API docs state that I need to pass them like `foo.com/api?a=val1&a=val2&a=val3` but when I pass that through `clj-http` as above it only does `foo.com/api?a=val3`.

(For more detail, I'm using Authorize.Net's version 3.1 CSV-based API and trying to add `x_line_item` which is defined to work as above.)

Comment: works for me. Note that :form-params generates a body with a=val1&a=val2&a=val3 while :query-params generates a query string.

Comment: Some issue here with the solution above. Using an array produces a set of parameters that include the corresponding index as part of the name, something like a[1]=foo&a[0]=bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually @dAni was correct. Passing a vector as above works correctly. The [debugging endpoint output from Authorize.Net](https://developer.authorize.net/tools/paramdump/index.php) only shows the last entry, but if you set the client email to one you control you will see the line items you send listed.